# Adding custom functionality to button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm new to iOS and Xcode. I added some buttons to my iPhone app and now I want to add to them functionality. On Xcode I went to the story board file, right click on a button and then there are story board segues there is costume. I'm clicking the + and nothing happen.

Comment: Have you set up anything in your implementation files for the buttons to link to?

Comment: Just implement an IBAction, IBActions can be selected from the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(youFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Person obviously trying to add an action in interface builder, why would you propose programmatical approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonSelected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Implement `-(void)yourButtonSelected` method

```
-(void)yourButtonSelected{

// Write your code
}
```